# Control legend color and order when joining two charts in Altair

Tags: altair

I am having difficulty getting the correct order for color in the legend.

I am trying to attain:

```
cash: blue
fixed_income: yellow
equity: red
```

I am charting two rows of three charts using the following dataframe 'dfl':

```
  trade_date account owner account_type asset  value  sort_asset
0 2002-01-02  p2_inv    p2          inv  cash    0.0           0
1 2002-01-03  p2_inv    p2          inv  cash    0.0           0
2 2002-01-04  p2_inv    p2          inv  cash    0.0           0
```

dfl.shape (76824, 7)

I have the following code:

```
df_p1 = dfl[dfl['owner'] == 'p1']
df_p2 = dfl[dfl['owner'] == 'p2']

base_p1 = alt.Chart(df_p1).mark_area().encode(
    x=alt.X('trade_date:T', title=""), 
    y=alt.Y('sum(value):Q', stack='normalize', title="Asset Allocation"), 
    color=alt.Color('asset:N', sort=['cash', 'fixed_income', 'equity']),
    order=alt.Order('sort_asset:N', sort='ascending')
).properties(
    width=120,
    height=160
).facet(
    column=alt.Column('account:N'), 
)
base_p2 = alt.Chart(df_p2).mark_area().encode(
    x=alt.X('trade_date:T', title=""), 
    y=alt.Y('sum(value):Q', stack='normalize', title="Asset Allocation"), 
    color=alt.Color('asset:N', sort=['cash', 'fixed_income', 'equity']),
    order=alt.Order('sort_asset:N', sort='ascending')
).properties(
    width=120,
    height=160
).facet(
    column=alt.Column('account:N'),
)

base_p1 & base_p2
```

When I run base_p1 or base_p2 by themselves, I get the correct legend. But when I join them together using & my legend and color changes to:

```
cash: blue
equity: yellow
fixed income: red
```

I also note I added in a sort_asset column in the DataFrame that I can use to sort the assets correctly, and I'm using it to ensure the stack is sorted properly.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple as I'm new to altair. What can I change in the code above to render the proper colors and orders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in Altair version 2: sorted fields are not preserved in compound charts. Some details (including ideas for workarounds) are here: https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/820

Altair 3.0 fixes this bug, and should be released some time in the coming week.